Calculate the probability of a peak in cyclical data using historical observations?
I find that using a histogram does not work for a sine wave because it has a lot of data points close to its peak. So I included to measure the distance traveled of values higher than our current observation_i.
My goal is to use a general method that works with very noisy cyclical data, and uses past observations to infer how likely it is that the latest (current) observation is a peak value (i.e. local maximum).
Below are the outputs of my python code to attempt to measure this but it is still affected a lot by any noise, and I would like to do it better (especially in the sawtooth data where at y=1 my algorithm estimates 50% probability of peak, which I think is too high given that it normally peaks around 2). How does one compute the actual probability that the current observed data_i is a peak using historical data that is cyclical and noisy? What method(s) should I have used?
Edit: To elaborate, I would like to build a function that is able to estimate the probability that the "current wave is peaking", i.e. that it will not go any higher. I.e. how do I build a function that plots the probability that we are at a local maxima.


import numpy as np
from scipy import signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd


### testing on SINE data

t1 = np.linspace(0, np.pi*2*3, num=int(100)*2*3)
signal1 = np.absolute(np.sin(t1))
noise1= np.random.rand(len(signal1),)/10  

data1 = signal1 + noise1

prob_is_peak = np.empty((len(data1),))
prob_is_peak[:] = np.nan

for i in range(1,len(data1)): # probability on distance and frequency
    
    data_i = data1[i]
    hist_data = data1[0:i]
    
    #distance
    hist_higher_than_i = hist_data[hist_data>data_i]
    distance_covered = data_i/hist_higher_than_i
    obs_mean_dist_covered = np.mean(distance_covered) 
    
    #frquency of lower values
    n_below_obs_i = len(hist_data[hist_data<data_i])
    n_obs = len(hist_data)
    obs_data_lower = n_below_obs_i / n_obs
    
    #probability of peak
    p_peak = obs_mean_dist_covered * obs_data_lower 


    prob_is_peak[i] = p_peak



plt.plot(data1, marker='.',ls='none',label='data')
plt.plot(prob_is_peak, lw=1,label='probability of peak')
plt.legend()





### testing on SAWTOOTH data

n_sawt = 6
t2 = np.linspace(0, 1, int(n_sawt*100))
signal2 = signal.sawtooth(2 * np.pi * n_sawt * t2)
noise2 = np.random.rand(len(signal2),)/10  
data2 = signal2 + noise2

data2 = data2 - np.nanmin(data2) # to keep values above 0



prob_is_peak2 = np.empty((len(data2),))
prob_is_peak2[:] = np.nan

for i in range(1,len(data2)): # probability on distance and frequency
    
    data_i = data2[i]
    hist_data = data2[0:i]
    
    #distance
    hist_higher_than_i = hist_data[hist_data>data_i]
    distance_covered = data_i/hist_higher_than_i
    obs_mean_dist_covered = np.mean(distance_covered) 
    
    #frquency of lower values
    n_below_obs_i = len(hist_data[hist_data<data_i])
    n_obs = len(hist_data)
    obs_data_lower = n_below_obs_i / n_obs
    
    #probability of peak
    p_peak = obs_mean_dist_covered * obs_data_lower 


    prob_is_peak2[i] = p_peak



plt.figure()
plt.plot(data2, marker='.',ls='none',label='data2')
plt.plot(prob_is_peak2, lw=1,label='probability of peak2')
plt.legend()


Your question is not so clear to me... Could you clarify it? Did you look into optimal filters/matched filters?

There's a lot of work on "zero-crossings" but that means crossing the horiontal line rather than peaks. But it's just a shift so maybe you could apply similar techniques. There's a professor at U Maryland who has done a lot of the work in this "zero crossings"  field but his name escapes me. If you really need his name, let me know and I'll find it.

Your "probability of a peak" plot makes little sense, because at the very least it should always be zero wherever the current value is less than its immediately preceding value.  I wonder what it is you are really trying to compute.

@Ggjj11 i have edited my question. Basically I just want to figure out what is the the likelihood that an observed value is at a peak. If it were a clean sinus wave we would know that when it is = 1 we have reached theoretical max. But how would I do this for a wave that is not sine, and is noisy?

@mlofton That sounds interesting, because just like you wrote it is a shift. I would be very happy if you could find his name!

@whuber you are right about it being zero if lower than preceding. If you had a lot of observed data, what method would you use to estimate the likelihood that the current observed value y is a maximum value of a noisy cyclical data set?

This is one of those statistical problems that IMHO requires a careful consideration of the underlying question and the loss function for the decision.  Specifically: what are the costs associated with incorrect determinations?  What do you gain by being right and what do you lose by being incorrect?  Do these losses depend on the values of the observations or not (and if not, why not)?  How frequently are you allowed to make these decisions?  Must you make them at every observation or not?

Optimal filters are connected to likelihood: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matched_filter https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/639622/298651 maybe someone else can connect the dots?

@litmus : This is the person ( link at bottom ) I was talking about. But I wouldn't take "zero-crossings" as the idea that will lead to a solution. It's just a suggestion and could be relevant. I think what whuber said above are questions to ask BEFORE you consider the concept of zero crossings. https://math.umd.edu/~bnk/

@mlofton thank you!

@litmus: You're welcome. I'm glad to help.
